# hola, hice un script en blender 2.92 para un operador y un panel super simple pero el operador no aparece, parece que no se registra cual es el error

Tags: script, operador, blender

El panel funciona bien aparece correctamente

```
import bpy
class OB_PT_Panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = 'panel hello'
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = 'Item'
    
    def draw(self, context):
        self.layout.operator(OB_OT_HelloWorld.bl_idname, text="hello world")
```

El operador no se registra y ya compare el código con algunos ejemplos sencillamente no veo el error por favor podrían ayudarme a entender que pasa

```
class OB_OT_HelloWorld(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = 'Hello World'
    bl_idname = 'object.HelloWorld'
    bl_options = {'REGISTER'}
    
    def execute(self, context):
        print("Hello World")
        return {"FINISHED"}
```

El Registro del panel es correcto

```
classes = (OB_PT_Panel, OB_OT_HelloWorld)  
            
def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
        
def unregister():
    for cls in reversed(classes):
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
    
else:
    unregister()
```

Comment: ya encontré el error no se puede utilizar camelcase  en el bl_idname